# escaping docker-compose template variables with ansible

Tags: ansible, docker-compose

I want to pass aws logs drive configurations using ansible scripts.

Following is the aws log configuration snippet.

```
logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-region: us-east-2
        awslogs-group: dev
        awslogs-stream: stream-{{.FullID}}
```

{{.FullID}} is a tag supported by docker-compose ansible throws the following error while trying to execute it.

```
{"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: unexpected '.'. String: version: '2
```

Is there a way to achieve this configuration with ansible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At minimum, the following should prevent templating engine from trying to interpret it:

```
awslogs-stream: stream-{{'{'}}{.FullID}}
```

But for clarity I'd put everything into a template:

```
awslogs-stream: "{{ 'stream-{{.FullID}}' }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try either this:

```
awslogs-stream: !unsafe "stream-{{.FullID}}"
```

or this:

```
awslogs-stream: stream-{{ '{{' }}.FullID{{ '}}' }}
```